# How do I route audio to my HDMI port instead of the display port

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

My Dell Studio 1747 notebook has an ATI radeon HD 4650 graphic card. The card has both HDMI as well as Display port output. However, the audio routes to the Display port instead of the HDMI. Since both are on the same adapter, I cannot choose between them in windows 8. Also, it does not matter which display I set as my main display.

How do I choose which port to route my audio to?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Some applications such as VLC allow you to specify the audio device. Can you make it work that way? Also a have you verified you are on the latest gfx drivers?

Comment: If both outputs are managed by the AMD GPU you could also try to take a look at the CPU Control Panel